# Is the first axis 0 or 1 in keras.layers.BatchNormalization()?

Tags: keras, batch-normalization

I am working on the 'Keras_Tutorial_v2a' by Andrew Ng on Coursera and I am confused about the axis parameter in keras.layers.BatchNormalization().

The first few layers of the model are:

```
X_input = Input(input_shape)
X = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv0')(X_input)
X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn0')(X)
```

Where input_shape is the shape of the images of the dataset:(height, width, channels). So it seems that axis=3 is referring to the channels, but shouldn't that be axis=2? I couldn't find documentation specifying this, but usually in python indices and axes begin at 0.

So either axes begins at 1 in this function, or there is something I am missing. Can anyone clarify this for me please? I'm sure it's something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tutorials and Keras/TensorFlow codebase, you will see `axis = 3` or `axis = -1`. This is what should be chosen, since the channel axis is 3 (or the last one, -1).

If you look in the original documentation, the default is `-1` (`3`rd in essence).

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization

Answer (score 1):

In Keras, dimensions ordered as `batch_size, height, width, channel`. So `channel` is the `axis=3`. You want to choose the axis index which represents your channels as you stated.